# How to convert a object to array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I'm trying to do a reduce, the following snippet is what I have right now:

```
 $push: {
                $round: {
                  $divide: [
                    { $subtract: [new Date(), "$created_at"] },
                    86400000
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            prodotti: { $push: "$items" },
            
            ordini: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            email: "$_id",
            frequency: "$frequency",
            monetary: "$monetary",
            recency: { $first: "$recency_array" },
            average_timing_purchase: { $avg: "$recency_array" }, // purchase average in days
            prodotti: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$prodotti",
                initialValue: [],
                in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
              }
            },
```

When I run the job it throws the following error:
PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $concatArrays only supports arrays, not object

My guess is because "$prodotti" is a object, I tried $objectToArray aggregation but I think I didn't get the syntax or where to use.

Comment: Can you add a MongoPlayground with sample data, attempted query?

Comment: I think, `prodotti` is an array, as you are able to use it in the `$reduce`. You are getting the error mostly because the elements of the array are not of array type. `$$this` represents an array element, as `$reduce` iterates over the `prodotti` array. When you want to use `$concatArrays`, the input to this operator are two arrays - one is the `$$value` and the other should be `[ "$$this" ]`. That said, you are better off knowing what data you are working with (than guessing).